# Error when using ActiveAdmin and Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, activeadmin, kaminari

I was using will_paginate to paginate my reports, however, I tried to add ActiveAdmin and I get errors. So I did some research and realized that AA uses kaminari, so I swapped from will_paginate to kaminari, but I get this error `undefined method`current_page' for #`because of this line of code`<%= paginate @reports %>`. Everything, is there a special way to install kaminari? Anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are using the same variable name and 2 or more actions. Try to use a different variable name.

```
def index
  @reports = Report.page(params[:page])
end

def list
  @report_list = Report.list.page(params[:page])
end
```

Try simple changing your variables. It should work!

Comment: Where is the Report.list from?

Comment: That was just an example showing to you, that you may have to work with different variable names. In that case `@reports` and `@report_list`.